# Flutter FCM Messages Sometimes not receiving when background?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm currently working on a Flutter project and using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to receive messages in the application.

Everything works perfectly when the app is in the foreground. However, I'm facing an issue when the app is in the background. The initial message is received when the app runs via debug, but subsequent FCM messages are not being received. The following log message is repeatedly printed in the console:

> D/FLTFireMsgReceiver( 2150): broadcast received for message

I've included my code below. How can I resolve this issue?"
I used `_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(...)` method to handle background messages.

Comment: You need to send the message as push notification by using this package

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications